# Using Kubernetes client-go lang to change Node Condition Status

Tags: go, kubernetes, openshift, kubectl, kubernetes-go-client

I need to patch or change the node condition status, any idea how to do that using go lang "k8s client" ?

Edit:
I can see that inside the Node interface there is patch, not sure about the usage, documentation lacks info about data should be sent, how to know what kind of data

```
Patch(ctx context.Context, name string, pt types.PatchType, data []byte, opts metav1.PatchOptions, subresources ...string) (result *v1.Node, err error)
```

Link: [Nodes Interface](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.0/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#CoreV1Client.Nodes) [Nodes Interface](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.0/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#NodeInterface)

**Edit2**: I am running below and am not getting any errors but yet it's not adding or patching the node condition.

```
Payload := `{ "op": "replace", "path": "/status/conditions/12","value": { "type": "QuayStateSmelik", "status": "False" }}`
bytePayload := []byte(Payload)
```

Then run:

```
node, err := clientset.CoreV1().Nodes().Patch(context.TODO(), "NodeName", types.StrategicMergePatchType, bytePayload, metav1.PatchOptions{})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Kubernetes Client issue on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/1096#issuecomment-1214656187) you need to add "status" as a subresource parameter, for example:

```
node, err := clientset.CoreV1().Nodes().Patch(context.TODO(), "<Node-Name>", types.JSONPatchType, bytesPayloadTT, metav1.PatchOptions{}, "status")
```